# Overloading subscript operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an example Map class in which I am trying to override the subscript operator. To allow users of the class to read and write to the Map.
Map["a"] being read, and Map["a"]="something" being the write of the class. However, I can't figure out how to use the assignment operator side of things, and allow a passed in value to replace it. Right now, if I try to assign a new value it just reads "segmentation fault"

Here is what I have so far:

```
VALUE_TYPE& Map::operator[](KEY_TYPE a){
    cout << "hmm" << endl;


}



Map& Map::operator=(const Map &rhs){
    //cout << "operator = " << endl;
}
```

Right now I don't have any of the code.. just wanted to see that they would get succesfully called.

What I can't seem to figure out is if I do something such as

```
Map["a"] = "hey";
```

I will get a segmentation fault. I was assuming that the assignment operator= would be called when I wanted to assign a specific key a new value. Am I doing something wrong?

By the way, VALUE_TYPE and KEY_TYPE are just defined as strings, each key has a value associated with it.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: At first look. The operator should be taking in a `type` not a `Map` right? Because `Map[a]` would return an element in the map. Not a map. Unless it is a map of maps.

Comment: The operator= assigns the entire map, not a single element.

Comment: You need a `return` statement in your `operator[]`. Also, the assignment operator for the map object has nothing to do with anything. Remove it.

Comment: You can avoid some unintended text substitutions, as well as reducing the stress on readers' eyes and ears, by not using SHOUTCASE for ordinary names. Reserve that for macro names. That's the usual convention: it reserves the most ugly notation for the most evil stuff.

Comment: Please turn your compiler warnings on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning to the map but to the object returned by `operator[]`.
(In `m["a"] = "hey";`, `m["a"]` is not a `Map`, it's a `VALUE_TYPE&`.)

The operator needs to return a reference to a valid object, otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

Smallest example I can come up with:

```
struct Mapp
{
    int& operator[](int i) { return member; }
    int member;
};

int main()
{
    Mapp m;
    m[0] = 12; // Assigns 12 to m.member
}
```

You also want to overload the const version of the operator.

Comment: wow that makes a lot of sense... wasn't returning an object to be assigned! Thank you!